# Is there a more efficient way to do this.( Show Hide Divs / Hide Previously shown Div)?

Tags: jquery

I am unfortunately not the best Jquery programmer but I thought I would give this a try to see what i could come up with. It works however I don't think it is the best way to accomplish what i am after.

HTML MARKUP:

```
<ul class="top-menu">
<li><a href="#" class="drop">Sign In</a>
    <div id="panel_1" class="panel left">
    CONTENT 1
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="#" class="drop">Register</a>
    <div id="panel_2" class="panel left">
    CONTENT 2
    </div>
</li>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var visId = null;
        $(".top-menu li a.drop").click(function () {

            var parent = $(this).parent();
            var panel = $(parent).find("div.panel");
            if ($(visId) != null && $(visId).is(":visible")) {
                if ($(visId).attr("id") != $(panel).attr("id")) {
                    $(visId).slideUp("fast");
                }
            }

            $(panel).slideDown(function () {
                $(this).slideDown();
                visId = $(this);
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: perhaps an explanation with words would help, what does this do?

Comment: when the menu item "Sign In" is clicked I slide down the hidden div, if the same menu item is clicked again, I don't want it to toggle / slide up, just stay visible. Secondly, when the user clicks my register link I want the "Sign In Div" to go bye bye :) Like I said this is working, I just don't like the way it looks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like so:

**Code**

```
$( function()
{
    var top_menu = $( 'ul.top-menu' ),
        panels = top_menu.find( 'div.panel' );

    top_menu.find( 'a.drop' ).click( function( e )
    {
        var target_panel = $( this ).parent().find( 'div.panel:hidden' );

        if( target_panel.length )
        {
            panels.filter( ':visible' ).slideUp( 'fast' );
            target_panel.slideDown();
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    } );
} );
```

**Live Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/8HZzh/

Comment: Cool, this works and you understand exactly what I am after... Nice!

Comment: This example does exactly what the originally posted code does but with less of it. Thanks you all rock!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".top-menu li a.drop").click(function () {
            var panel = $(this).parent().find("div.panel");
            $('.top-menu li div.panel').slideUp("fast");
            $(panel).slideDown();
        });

    });
```

this can help

Comment: You've got a reference to `parent` which is not defined. There is also no need to pass `panel` back into the jQuery factory--it already is a jQuery collection. You would also gain efficiency by obtaining a reference to the panel collection outside of the click function--this would avoid re-querying the DOM for the same elements on every click.

Answer (score 1):

You bet

http://jsfiddle.net/xPTNS/

```
.panel
{
    display:none;
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".panel:first").toggle();
    $(".top-menu li a.drop").click(function () {
        $(".panel").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Better solution for multiple items

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".panel:first").show();
    $(".top-menu li a.drop").click(function () {
        $(".panel").slideUp();
        $(this).siblings().slideDown();
    });
});
```

Comment: This results in the first panel showing at load, which may not be desirable. Also, if there is more than two panels, it causes multiple panels to show at once. ( http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/xPTNS/3/ )

Comment: @JAAlude idk what came over me... http://jsfiddle.net/tyupQ/ I must be tired (which I am) :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$(".top-menu li a.drop").click(function () {
    var panel = $(this).next();
    if($(panel).not(":visible")){
        $(".panel").each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":visible"))
                $(this).slideUp("slow");
        });
        $(panel).slideDown("slow");
     }
});
```

Though I feel as if there is a far more efficient way of doing so.

Comment: It is a bit more than just toggling the state, there may be more than two ele

Comment: Right, I was unsure of exactly what you wanted to do. I will update my answer.

Comment: You would gain efficiency by avoiding calls to `$()` for variables which are already jQuery collections, as well as for selectors which have already been matched.

Answer (score 0):

In your code at many places you were wrapping a jQuery object into `$()` which is not required because its already a `jQuery` object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visId = null;
    $(".top-menu li a.drop").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var parent = $this.parent();
        var panel = parent.find("div.panel");
        $this
        .closest('.top-menu')
        .find('div.panel:not(#'+$this.next().attr('id')+')')
        .slideUp("fast", function(){
          panel.slideDown();
        });
        return false;
    }).eq(0).click();
});
```

Comment: OK, I can clean the extra variables up easy enough. Other than that is there a better way to accomplish what I am doing?

Comment: Can you check my edited answer now. Is that you are looking for?

Comment: Throws and error: Uncaught Type Error: cannot call method 'attr' of undefined

Comment: $ was missing at one place can you try now my edited answer, thanks.

Comment: It toggles the previous back up just fine however, if you click the link if the div is already visible it "fires the toggle again"

Comment: What do you want it to happen? In thought you want it that way since there is not explaination in your question.

Comment: Please try my edited answer it works as expected and I have created a fiddle also take a look http://jsfiddle.net/B3htg/2/

Comment: There are several calls to `$()` which are unnecessary. Store a reference to the jQuerized `this` element and use that reference.

Comment: @CrazyzCoderz - Did you take a look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/B3htg/2/ or my edited answer?